# window made by python selenium disappears immediately

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://youtube.com")
```

After I run this code, window appears, but it disappears 3 or 4 seconds later.

In others' computer, the window doesn't get closed.
Is there anything wrong in my code?
Then how can I solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: did you check chromedriver version and Chrome version compatibility?

Comment: Yeah i did and i dont know the reason it's not working

Comment: Do you see any error in the console? If yes, can you share it in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***After I run this code, window appears, but it disappears 3 or 4 seconds later.***

When you say the above, my assumption is that code launches chrome browser, opens YouTube website and then it closes the browser without any errors. Is that true? If yes, then that is an expected behaviour in Python Selenium.

When the `browser` object has reached the last line of code, it terminates itself closing the browser.

If you want the browser to remain open, then you need to detach the browser and driver using the `detach` arguments in `ChromeOptions`. See the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
browser.get("http://youtube.com")
```