# Chrome browser closes immediately after being launched with selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

Hello im trying to run the following code in python.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

def verify_title():
    # Navigate to the website
    driver.get("https://google.com")

    # Get the title of the page
    title = driver.title

    # Verify the title
    expected_title = "Google"
    if title == expected_title:
        print("Title verification successful!")
    else:
        print(f"Title verification failed. Expected '{expected_title}, but got '{title}'.")

    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    verify_title()
```

It does run successfully which outputs "Title verification successful!" however the chrome browser closes immediately.

Ive even removed the code
driver.quit() to see if that made any difference but still same problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the code as below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
```

Refer this answer for more details about `detach` option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77402087/7598774