# first steps with selenium dont work properly

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i don't know what exactly is the problem, but i see lots of red

CODE:

```
from selenium import webdriver

window = webdriver.Edge("C:\\Nowy\\msedgedriver.exe")

window.maximize_window()
window.get("https://www.google.pl/?hl=pl")
window.close()
```

ERRORS:

```
C:\Users\Talos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Talos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Talos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
  File "C:\Users\Talos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 75, in driver_location
    browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Talos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    window = webdriver.Edge("C:\\Nowy\\msedgedriver.exe")
  File "C:\Users\Talos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Talos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
  File "C:\Users\Talos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 40, in get_path
    msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i tried `window = webdriver.Edge("C:\\Nowy\\msedgedriver.exe")`
or      `window = webdriver.Edge("C:/Nowy/msedgedriver.exe")`
end same with letter r before C: but nothing works. i have proper version of webdriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using latest selenium, just change the code as below, `SeleniumManager` will take care of `chromedriver.exe` management::

```
from selenium import webdriver

window = webdriver.Edge()

window.maximize_window()
window.get("https://www.google.pl/?hl=pl")
window.close()
```

No need of setting the `chromedriver.exe` path manually. Refer below answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: yup. thanks. its working now, but after it opened google, it will close almost immediately.

Comment: It's closing because of your code, `window.close()`

Comment: Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77402087/7598774

Answer (score 1):

Try *webdriver_manager* which auto-downloads and updates the webdriver for different browsers including Edge.

https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager#use-with-edge

You'll first need to install the webdriver-manager module to use it.

`pip install webdriver-manager`

For Selenium 4.x

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

print("1. Install driver")
s = Service(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
print("2. Setup Edge")
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s)
print("3. Fetch URL")
driver.get("https://www.google.pl/?hl=pl")
```