# Selenium webdriver handling errors

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

Hello I am a beginner to python and selenium and I wanted to make a simple program that open google chrome. Am using PyCharm.

This is the code:
[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KLj5.png)

And this is the errors that are being thrown:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJTED.png)

I have tried to reinstall selenium or the web driver but it just doesn't work, also at the start I used the path that is in the top side of the image, and after that I saw someone that said that maybe the `webdriver_manager` could fix it. Needless to say it didn't work.

Comment: Do not share the code and error as image. Edit your question and share it in the form of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.techwithtim.net/")
```

No need of `WebDriverManager` when you use latest selenium. Refer below answer for more details:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: it works now, but the problem now is that it ends the program automatically for some reason, do you know something about that?

Comment: Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77402087/7598774