# Chromedriver window getting closed after the code gets executed

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run the Chromedriver using Selenium in Python.
But after executing my code, the Chromedriver window gets stopped immediately and gets an error message.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

path = "X:/test/chromedriver.exe"

s = Service(path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
url = "https://www.nike.com/in/w/mens-shoes-nik1zy7ok"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(3)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if height == new_height:
        break
    height = new_height
```

This is the log that I'm getting in the console:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58103/devtools/browser/6b68ccf6-fc7e-4a29-8ff7-bd0ec67924ca
[14872:16644:0326/155508.942:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(970)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14872:16644:0326/155509.194:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(970)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
```

I want the Chromedriver window to stay open until I close it manually. And resolve the error showing in the terminal.

Comment: Check this answer if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77402087/7598774

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a breakpoint to pause the script at a location, which will prevent the browser from closing:

```py
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

or the simplified version of that:

```py
breakpoint()
```

To continue from the breakpoint, type `c` and press Enter in the console.